# psycopg2 formatting for bulk insertion

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm inserting rows this way, `data` being a dictionary of several `fieldname: fieldvalue` items:

```
def add_row(self, data, table): #data is a dictionary
    columns = data.keys()
    values = []

    for column in columns:
        if isinstance(data[column], list): #checking for json values
            values.append(Json(data[column])) 
        elif isinstance(data[column], dict):
            values.append(Json(data[column])) 
        else:
            values.append(data[column])
    insert_statement = 'insert into %s ' % table + '(%s) values %s'
    self.cur.execute(insert_statement, (AsIs(','.join(columns)), tuple(values)))
    self.conn.commit()
    print "added %s" % table
```

But now I'd like to insert rows in bulk to improve performance and reduce I/O usage. The problem is that I couldn't find the right way to do it. The following function throws (`data` being a list of the items described above):

> ```
> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["
> LINE 1: ...,category_id,initial_quantity,base_price) VALUES ([u'Entrega...
> ```

```
def add_row_bulk(self, data, table): #data is a dictionary
    columns = data[0].keys()
    value_rows = []
    for e in data:
        columns = e.keys()
        values = []

        for column in columns:
            if isinstance(e[column], list): #checking for json values
                values.append(Json(e[column])) 
            elif isinstance(e[column], dict):
                values.append(Json(e[column])) 
            else:
                values.append(e[column])
        value_rows.append(AsIs(values))

    cols = (AsIs(','.join(columns)))
    query = self.cur.mogrify("INSERT INTO item (%s) VALUES %s", (cols, tuple(value_rows)))
    self.cur.execute(query) 
    self.conn.commit()
    print "added %s" % table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple problems with your SQL generating code.

First off, `AsIs(values)` will not `mogrify` into a value row, like you seem to be hoping. Testing it, it seems to be equivalent to `AsIs(str(values))`. That's the output you're seeing in your thrown error.

What worked in your working example was using `mogrify` on separate tuples of values. Add `tuple(values)` to `value_rows`, not `AsIs(values)`.

Secondly, to specify the values for inserting a number of rows in one insert statement, you need [SQL syntax similar to the following](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html):

```
... VALUES (1, 'x'), (2, 'y'), (3, 'z')
```

Note that the list of value lists doesn't have `(` `)` around it. There's nothing (that I'm aware of) that's magically going to `mogrify` into a list like that. Certainly a `tuple` won't.

So you need to do something like:

```
self.cur.mogrify('INSERT INTO item (%s) VALUES %s,%s,%s,%s',
                 (cols, value_row1, value_row2, value_row3, value_row4))
```

which means you need to do a little more work to generate the two arguments to `mogrify`, because the number of rows isn't known in advance. To generate the first argument, you can do something like:

```
'INSERT INTO item (%s) VALUES ' + ','.join(['%s'] * len(value_rows))
```

And the second argument needs to be a sequence with the first value `cols`, and the rest the contents of `value_rows`. One way to get that:

```
[cols] + value_rows
```